# Logic of statement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, factorial

I can see the mathematical implication but could not get the logic, why $5!$ is equal to $^6P_3$? Please help proving why both the expressions are equal without mathematical manipulation!In any case, does there exist any generalization of the above property?

Comment: "without mathematical implications" --- what does that mean?

Comment: i mean without mathematical manipulations...

Comment: I don't think it's true that for every $n$ there exist $r$ and $s$ such that $n!={}^rP_s$ (except trivially with say $s=1$ or $s=r-1$).

Comment: okay, but why this is true? mere co-incidence or any logic?

Comment: @Gerry what does this notation mean ?

Comment: I vote for coincidence.

Comment: @Peter, if you mean the ${}^rP_s$, it's the number of permutations of $r$ things taken $s$ at a time.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Is it possible to prove that there doesn't exist any further generalised solution of the given expression?

Comment: @Peter, ${}^rP_s=r!/(r-s)!$. Hawk, I don't know for sure, but my guess is there may be a few more solutions, but just a few, and it may not be easy to prove you have a complete list.

Comment: @GerryMyerson.Okay, so it seems like this question is little out of bounds! :)

Comment: @Peter.Sorry, but it is little hard to retrieve the information from your comment. What is PARI by the way?

Comment: Let (a,b,c) a triple, such that a!/(a-b)!=c!. Then the triples found are (6,3,5) (10,3,6) (10,4,7) (24,20,23) (120,115,119). I forced a>b+1 and b>1 to eliminate the trivial cases.

Comment: Okay, so are these all the possible solutions or just a few?

Comment: PARI is a computational tool.

Answer (score 1):

As $\frac{(n!)!}{n!}=(n!-1)!$ for all n , there are infinitely many nontrivial triples (a,b,c) with $\frac{a!}{(a-b)!}=c!$

Choose a=n! , b=n!-n , c=n!-1

Comment: Are there infinitely many integers $k$ such that $n!/r!$ is *never* equal to $k!$?

Comment: Besides these special solutions , I only found (10,3,6) and (10,4,7) with the calculation tool PARI so far.

Comment: can't there be other solutions other than this form?

Comment: Maybe, there are other solutions, but for a,b,c <= 1000, I did not find any more.

Comment: @Goos, $k!!/(k!-1)!=k!$.

Comment: The question can be formulated as follows : What are the integer solutions for the equation a!.b!=c! ? Without loss of generality a<=b and to avoid trivial cases, let a>1. It is easy to show that b cannot exceed a!-1 and c is between b and a+b. To avoid also the above cases, let additionally be b<a!-1 . Then the only solutions seems to be (6,7,10).

Comment: Using Bertrands postulate (for all integer x>1 , there is a prime p with x<p<2x), it can be shown that a factorial greater than 1 is never a perfect square, so that a=b cannot work. Perhaps this result can be improved using sylvesters theorem ( the product of k consecutive integers greater than k has a prime factor greater than k ).

Comment: @gerry right, I missed this additional special case, although I used it in my answer. I apparently was confused.

Comment: I have no idea how the equality can be seen without calculating anything, especially in the case (6,7,10). Also, it seems out of reach to find ALL solutions of a!b!=c!.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, 3rd edition, problem B23: Equal products of factorials, begins,

Suppose that $$n!=a_1!a_2!\dots a_r!,\quad r\ge2,\quad a_1\ge a_2\ge\dots\ge a_r\ge2$$ A trivial example is $$a_1=a_2!\dots a_r!-1,\quad n=a_2!\dots a_r!$$ Dean Hickerson notes that the only nontrivial examples with $n\le410$ are $$9!=7!3!3!2!,\quad10!=7!6!=7!5!3!,\quad16!=14!5!2!$$ and asks if there are any others. Jeffrey Shallit and Michael Easter have extended the search to $n=18160$ and Chris Caldwell has shown that any other $n$ is greater than $10^6$.

Elsewhere, Guy cites 
MR1646003 (99i:11025) Passow, Eli, On the solutions of $n!=m!r!$,  Far East J. Math. Sci. 6 (1998), no. 3, 337–344. According to the review by Nikos Tzanakis, the author proves that if $r,j,k$ are positive integers, then $$(r+j+k)!=(r+j)!r!$$ has no solution with $j\le1914$ other than $(r,j,k)=(6,1,3)$.